# What exactly does 'must possess unrestricted work authorization' mean?

Tags: united-states, internship, international, remote-work, graduate

I've been checking out remote USA internships to apply to. Some specifically mention that even though this is a remote internship, they are not hiring candidates from outside the US. But there are some that don't specifically mention this, and I assume that this means they will offer the remote internships to people residing outside of the USA, but then I read this line:

> "Must possess unrestricted work authorization."

What exactly does this mean? Because at least 5 internship descriptions that I want to apply to have this same requirement.

Answer (score 9):

I think [Matt Pickering's answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-unrestricted-right-to-work-in-the-US-mean) covers this:

> #### What does unrestricted right to work in the US mean?
>
> In the USA this is either US citizenship, possessing a Green Card or having an unrestricted [EAD document](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-processes-and-procedures/employment-authorization-document) in another visa status. Any of these categories allows you to work for anyone at-will with no effort on the part of the employer except to hire you.

So even if they don't explicitly specify they are not hiring candidates from outside the US, they might as well have.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Guess I'll have to look deeper to find some companies that don't have this particular requirement!

Comment: I think so, good luck!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes; I wonder if that would also be true for the companies which explicitly state that "they are not hiring candidates from outside the US". Outside can refer to two things, nationality and residence.

Comment: I feel I must point out that, a job requiring you to be a US citizen, is indeed a legal requirement in the US.  I will admit I have never seen it refer to as "unrestricted right to .." though.

Comment: @Glorfindel When they say they are not hiring from outside the US, that is most often in reference to the visa requirements. They are stating that they are not willing to sponsor someone coming on a work visa. Many visas are restricted to just the company that sponsored that person.